# unable to install apollo/react-hooks , requires peer of graphql

Tags: reactjs, graphql

While installing `npm install @apollo/react-hooks`, I got the following error message. It tells me about installing graphql with a version higher than 14.3.1, but I have 15.0 installed.

[image]

```
npm WARN @apollo/react-common@3.1.4 requires a peer of graphql@^14.3.1 but none is installed. You must install peer dependencies yourself.      
npm WARN @apollo/react-components@3.1.5 requires a peer of graphql@^14.3.1 but none is installed. You must install peer dependencies yourself.  
npm WARN @apollo/react-hoc@3.1.5 requires a peer of graphql@^14.3.1 but none is installed. You must install peer dependencies yourself.
npm WARN graphql-tag@2.10.3 requires a peer of graphql@^0.9.0 || ^0.10.0 || ^0.11.0 || ^0.12.0 || ^0.13.0 || ^14.0.0 but none is installed. You 
must install peer dependencies yourself.
npm WARN react-apollo@3.1.5 requires a peer of graphql@^14.3.1 but none is installed. You must install peer dependencies yourself.
npm WARN tsutils@3.17.1 requires a peer of typescript@>=2.8.0 || >= 3.2.0-dev || >= 3.3.0-dev || >= 3.4.0-dev || >= 3.5.0-dev || >= 3.6.0-dev || >= 3.6.0-beta || >= 3.7.0-dev || >= 3.7.0-beta but none is installed. You must install peer dependencies yourself.
npm WARN @apollo/react-hooks@3.1.5 requires a peer of graphql@^14.3.1 but none is installed. You must install peer dependencies yourself.       
npm WARN optional SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: fsevents@2.1.2 (node_modules\fsevents):
npm WARN notsup SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: Unsupported platform for fsevents@2.1.2: wanted {"os":"darwin","arch":"any"} (current: {"os":"win32","arch":"x64"})
npm WARN optional SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: fsevents@1.2.13 (node_modules\watchpack\node_modules\fsevents):
npm WARN notsup SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: Unsupported platform for fsevents@1.2.13: wanted {"os":"darwin","arch":"any"} (current: {"os":"win32","arch":"x64"})
npm WARN optional SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: fsevents@1.2.13 (node_modules\jest-haste-map\node_modules\fsevents):
npm WARN notsup SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: Unsupported platform for fsevents@1.2.13: wanted {"os":"darwin","arch":"any"} (current: {"os":"win32","arch":"x64"})
npm WARN optional SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: fsevents@1.2.13 (node_modules\webpack-dev-server\node_modules\fsevents):
 >= 3.6.0-beta || >= 3.7.0-dev || >= 3.7.0-beta but none is installed. You must install peer dependencies yourself.
npm WARN @apollo/react-hooks@3.1.5 requires a peer of graphql@^14.3.1 but none is installed. You must install peer dependencies yourself.       
npm WARN optional SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: fsevents@2.1.2 (node_modules\fsevents):
npm WARN notsup SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: Unsupported platform for fsevents@2.1.2: wanted {"os":"darwin","arch":"any"} (current: {"os":"win32","arch":"x64"})
npm WARN optional SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: fsevents@1.2.13 (node_modules\watchpack\node_modules\fsevents):
npm WARN notsup SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: Unsupported platform for fsevents@1.2.13: wanted {"os":"darwin","arch":"any"} (current: {"os":"win32","arch":"x64"})
npm WARN optional SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: fsevents@1.2.13 (node_modules\jest-haste-map\node_modules\fsevents):
npm WARN notsup SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: Unsupported platform for fsevents@1.2.13: wanted {"os":"darwin","arch":"any"} (current: {"os":"win32","arch":"x64"})
npm WARN optional SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: fsevents@1.2.13 (node_modules\webpack-dev-server\node_modules\fsevents):
32","arch":"x64"})
```

Comment: The caret in ^14.3.1 doesn't just mean *"higher than"*, it allows higher *minor versions*, `14.3.1 <= version < 15.0.0`.

Comment: You have graphql 15. You need to downgrade it to 14. [What is caret ^ in package.json?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22345808/2873538)

Answer (score 0):

From the official github repo it seems like you need to install the following peer dependencies & also `graphql` should be < 15.0.0 since `^` means minor release i.e >= 14.5.8 and < 15.0.0

So do this `npm install graphql@14.6.0`

Comment: That's not what your screenshot shows, that says graphql of * (any version)

Comment: That doesn't seem to be the correct package, and the correct one seems to be deprecated: https://github.com/apollographql/react-apollo

Comment: i still don't get how to interpret ^ 14.3.1. how do u know that it has to be less than 15.0.0 ?

Comment: @user2371290 play with this https://semver.npmjs.com/ you'll get it.

Answer (score 0):

run this command

```sh
npm uninstall grapql
```

then

```sh
npm install graphql
```